# Why a jet is always shaped as a 24 degrees cone?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

When a fluid enters with high momentum into another fluid with different density it always forms a cone.I have read that this cone is always about 24 degrees.

What is the physical reason or mathematical proof for this?

EDIT

https://engineering.dartmouth.edu/~d30345d/.../chap9.p.. I attach a link.

Comment: Provide citations for the claim and we might be able to help more.

Comment: [Some Googling suggests](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v178/n4526/abs/178205a0.html) this is the result of a calculation reported in *Tollmien, W. , Z. angewandte Math. und Mech., 6, 468 (1926)*. Your library may be able to get you a copy of this. More Googling suggests that cone angles vary a lot from the calculated value.

Comment: In fact the abstract disagrees with the OP's assertion, since the *measured* half-angles are between 7 and 20 degrees. A fluid dynamics calculation done 90 years ago is historically interesting, but the state of the art has progressed a bit since then!

Comment: @alephzero You could expand on this state of the art instead of scoffing

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: @tpg2114 ttps://engineering.dartmouth.edu/~d30345d/books/EFM/chap9.pdf

Comment: @veronika Still doesn't work. I get a 404 with both the original in your post and the one in you comment (even after I add the 'h' missing from the front part). I'll let others work to answer your question.

Comment: @tpg2114 For some reason, there's a zero-width space between the "d" and "f" in ".pdf", which expands to "%E2%80%8B" in the address bar. Remove it, and it works (or click [here](https://engineering.dartmouth.edu/~d30345d/books/EFM/chap9.pdf)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a rough rule of thumb, nothing more, for the case of a turbulent jet consisting of the same fluid as its environment. Very often the angle is roughly in the range of somewhere between $20^\circ$ and $26^\circ$ or so. If the fluids are (very) different, all bets are off; lots of things could happen, and lots of different kinds of jets are possible.

Comment: Is it true just for turbulent jets? OP mentions a density ratio exists also. I don't recall seeing such a guideline, although I don't doubt they exist. But it might be more than just because it is turbulent. The density ratio may come into play too.

Comment: I had overlooked that bit about different density. The number I gave is for a jet of essentially identical fluid as the surroundings. If the fluids are different then, yes, you're absolutely right. For example, a water jet in air can remain much more narrow than those 24 degrees.

Comment: So as @Veronika asked, what is the physical/math derivation as to why, in the equal density case, comes out to approx. 24 degrees? I don't see any answer.

Comment: This is turbulence we are talking about. There is no first-principles derivation of the growth rate for the turbulent jet (just as there is no such derivation for the mean flow profile of, say, turbulent pipe flow). With a significant amount of effort one can derive a similarity solution (see, e.g., Pope's book "*Turbulent Flow*", or Schlichting's "*Boundary Layer Theory*") and demonstrate the linear growth of the jet, but the growth *rate* remains dependent on a free parameter which needs to be found experimentally.